# Anova table for pscl:zeroinfl

Tags: r, anova, pscl

We're trying to model a count variable with excessive zeros using a zero-inflated poisson (as implemented in pscl package). Here is a (simplified) output showing both categorical and continuous explanatory variables:

```
library(pscl)
> m1 <- zeroinfl(y ~ treatment + some_covar, data = d, dist = 
"poisson")
> summary(m1)


Count model coefficients (poisson with log link):
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       3.189253   0.102256  31.189  < 2e-16 ***
treatmentB       -0.282478   0.107965  -2.616  0.00889 ** 
treatmentC        0.227633   0.103605   2.197  0.02801 *  
some_covar        0.002190   0.002329   0.940  0.34706    

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)       0.67251    0.74961   0.897   0.3696  
treatmentB       -1.72728    0.89931  -1.921   0.0548 .
treatmentC       -0.31761    0.77668  -0.409   0.6826  
some_covar       -0.03736    0.02684  -1.392   0.1640
```

summary gave us some good answers but we are looking for a ANOVA-like table. So, the question is: is it ok to use car::Anova to obtain such table?

```
> Anova(m1)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

Response: y
           Df   Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
treatment   2 30.7830  2.068e-07 ***
some_covar  1  0.8842     0.3471
```

It seems to work fine but i'm not really sure whether is a valid approach since documentation is missing (seems like is only considering the 'count model' part?). Do you recommend to follow this approach or there is a better way?